# Hyper-V VM CPU usage monitoring

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2016, task-manager, process-explorer

I'm migrating a number of VM's from one host to another (Win 2012R2 to Win 2016) and am noticing much higher CPU usage on the new host (quite a lot higher).

I was seeing this on Task Explorer so decided to use Process Explorer to try and get a better view of which VM's were using the most CPU.

There is a huge difference between what is reported in Task Manager and what is reported in Process Explorer.

I currently have over 60% CPU utilization reported in Task Explorer compared to 4-5% in Process Explorer.

In Task Explorer, all VM's running under Hyper-V come under one entry, which itself is around 40%, while in Process Explorer, vmcompute.exe is around 1%.

I'm not sure what to trust.

Any ideas on what is causing this behaviour?

Thanks.

Comment: Something about the way Hyper-V runs VMs prevents them from showing CPU usage under the VM process. Task Manager will report real system CPU but Process Explorer doesn't. You can use `Get-VM` in Powershell for a point-in-time look at VM CPU

Answer (score 3):

One of the methods of gathering information about VMs is "Measure-VM" PowerShell cmdlet. It will require "Enable-VMResourceMetering" in the VM.

The example of using it:

Get-VM | Enable-VMResourceMetering

Measure-VM

Also, you can take a look at Veeam One Community edition (https://www.veeam.com/virtual-server-management-one-free.html) which is one of the best monitoring and analytic tools for the virtual environments.